# Expo Vector Icons Not Displaying

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a detached Expo project that utilizes `@expo/vector-icons`, but it is not loading the vector icons on the release build variant.

In debug the vector icons display properly (see picture below), but in release, they do not display at all. I've tried running locally using `expo start --no-dev --minify` for local "release" testing, but still fail to get any icons on the device.
[image]

Another issue that I have found is that the `onLoad` callback for Images is not working. I've had to use the following workaround on Android for images in order to get the images to load properly on Android.

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios' ) {

    return (

        <View style={[style, styles.fullBackground]}>
            <Animated.Image 
                {...props}
                source={thumbnailSource}
                style={{ opacity: this.thumbnailAnimated }}
                blurRadius={2}
                onLoad={this.handleThumbnailLoad}
            />

            <Animated.Image 
                {...props}
                source={source}
                style={[styles.imageOverlay, { opacity: this.imageAnimated }, style]}
                onLoad={this.onImageLoad}
            />

        </View>

    );

} else {

    return (

        <View style={[style, styles.fullBackground]}>

            <Image 
                {...props}
                source={source}
                style={[styles.imageOverlay, { opacity: 1 }, style]}
            />

        </View>

    );

}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^1.1.3",
    "@unimodules/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "~5.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-ads-facebook": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.0.0",
    "expokit": "^36.0.0",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "geofirex": "0.0.6",
    "geopoint": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-animated-linear-gradient": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.4.5",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-mask-loader": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-share": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-super-ellipse-mask": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-text-gradient": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-unified-contacts": "^2.0.0-pre.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "recyclerlistview": "^1.3.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "geofirestore": "^3.3.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've tried quite a few different things, such as:

- Removing node_modules and re-running `npm install`
- Upgrading from Expo SDK 35 to Expo SDK 36
- Re-checking Expo documentation on upgrading SDKs (This project originated as SDK 32)

I'm at a bit of a loss on why this is occurring. Even talked with some people from Expo and they were unsure about why this might be happening (especially the Image onLoad callback). It's worth noting that the iOS build works correctly in development and release.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Comment: @EI-01 I don't recall tbh. Probably, but this was years ago when I ejecting from an Expo app was still a thing.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was able to resolve my issue by running the command `expo install @expo/vector-icons`

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, `react-native-vector-icons` wasn't linked to my project. So, run this command:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

made the trick for me.

Of course, you must have previously installed `react-native-vector-icons` module, something like:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```